# How to scroll the content inside a specific div only

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

I have inside my page a calendar view with all months of the year. This div has then a vertical scroll bar to give the possibility to the user to select his date.
The content of the div is loaded in AJAX using jQuery.load

I want to scroll the content of this specific div only to display the actual month first (every month calendar has is own anchor).

I found a solution, this scroll the div and display the actual month but it move also the all page.

My HTML code:

```
<div id="calendar_view" style="height:250px, overflow-x: auto;">
  <a id="January" name="January">
  <table> ... January month </table>
  <a id="February" name="February">
  <table> ... February month </table>
  .....
</div>
```

My JS code:

```
jQuery('#July','#calendar_view').get(0).scrollIntoView();
```

Any id using or not jQuery ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: No need for `jQuery('#July','#calendar_view')`, since you're searching by id: `jQuery('#July')`

Comment: You can set the `scrollHeight` property of an element with overflow to scroll somewhere within that element. So just calculate the position of the target element within your container and set the result as scrollheight.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322579/how-to-scroll-the-content-inside-a-specific-div-only

Comment: @CBroe : I was thinking that the scrollHeight property is a read-only attributes ... How can I have the position inside the div container and set it ?

Comment: No, scrollHeight is not read-only. As for how to find an elements position with jQuery ... Google helps :-P